# Android Java show error message when user selects date before today

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Below is my code of Datepicker allowing user to select dates and updates the textview with the selected date. How do I update the textview with an error message when user selects the date before today?

```
public void startCalender() {

    txtTrigger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calTrigger);
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            updateLabel();
        }
    };
    txtTrigger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DatePickerDialog(DisplayCeeAct.this, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
}

private void updateLabel() {
    String no = "<font color='red'>NO</font>.";
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());

    if (myCalendar.after(myCalendar.getTime())){
        txtTrigger.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
    else {
        txtTrigger.setText(Html.fromHtml(no), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Compare dates. `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` will give you current date. Use [compareTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo(java.util.Calendar)) to compare that with picked date.

Comment: Hello Ishita, if i used if (myCalendar.after(myCalendar.getTime())){}, it can update the textview with selected date, but the confusing part is setting text when user selected the past dates.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this line is crashing:

```
txtTrigger.setText(Html.fromHtml(no), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

A better approach would be:

```
txtTrigger.setText("NO");
txtTrigger.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```